# elog file of Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I want to understand the elog file of omnet++. What does the terms MS, BS, CM and CL etc means. 
Which terms are showing sending messages and which terms are showing receiving messages? I will then calculate the ratio of sending messages to receiving messages by using awk.

Comment: Eventlog file format is described in [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:eventlog-file-format). However, instead of calculating a ratio from an elog file you should consider introducing an own statistic (for example scalar) in C++ code of your model.

Comment: Thank you so much.
How should i do that in omnet? If i want to caculate the number of messages sent by a node and the number of messages received by the one hop node?

Comment: To calculate the number of messages sent by node just add a new variable in the definition of your class, then set it to zero in `initialize()`, and  increment it every time after sending a new message. In `finish()` add `recordScalar()` with the desired name and your variable. The same do for number of received messages.

Comment: Thank you Jerzy. Can i calculate the packet delivery ratio of MAC layer in inet by setting these variables?

Comment: Yes. You can obtain two separate scalars (i.e. number of sent and number of received packets) in results, and then calculate ratio during post processing. Or you can use signals as statistics and calculate the ratio during simulation.

Comment: will you please see this question FDM(frequency division multiplexing) at MAC layer in omnet++